# Performance Issues with .net core api and nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nest, traefik, .net-core-3.1

Description:
We use nginx as a reverse proxy, that splits up the load to multiple backend servers that are running a Graphql interface using HotChocolate (.net core 3.1). The Graphql interface then triggers an ElasticSearch Call (using the official NEST Library).

Problem:
We start the system with 4 backend servers and one nginx reverse proxy and load test it with JMeter. That is working absolutely great. It is also performing well when we kill the 4th pod.
The problem only jumps in when we have two (or one) pods left. Nginx starts to return only errors and does no longer split up the load to the two remaining servers.

What we tried:

1. We thought that the elastic search query is performing badly, which in turn could block the backend. When executing against the query against the elastic search directly, we have a much higher performance. So that should not be the problem.
2. Our second approach was that the graphql.net library is bogus, so we replaced it with HotChocolate, which had no effect at all.
3. When we replace the graphql interface with an REST API interface it IS suddenly working?!
4. We played around with the nginx config but couldn't find settings that actually fixed it.
5. We replaced the nginx with traefik, but also the same result.
6. What we discovered is that as soon as we will pod three the number of ESTABLISH Connections on the reverse proxy suddenly doubles (without any additional incoming). => Maybe it is waiting for the timeout of these connections and blocks any additionally incoming one?!

We very much appreciate any help.
Thank you very much.

If you want/need to know anything else, please let me know!

Update: I did some changes to the code. It's working better now, but when scaling from one pod to two we have a performance drop for about 20-30 seconds. Why is that? how can we improve that?

We get this error from nginx:

```
[warn] 21#21: *9717 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: dummy.prod.com, request: "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.20.0.5:5009/graphql", host: "dummy.prod.com:81"
nginx_1   | 2020/09/14 06:01:24 [error] 21#21: *9717 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: dummy.prod.com, request: "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.20.0.5:5009/graphql", host: "dummy.prod.com:81"
nginx_1   | 172.20.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2020:06:01:24 +0000] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 504 167 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/14)" "-"
```

nginx config:

```
upstream dummy {
    server dummy0:5009 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server dummy1:5009 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server dummy3:5009 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server dummy2:5009 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
  listen       80;

  location / {

    proxy_connect_timeout                   180s;
    proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
    proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

    proxy_buffering                         off;
    proxy_buffer_size                       128k;
    proxy_buffers                           4 128k;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;

    proxy_request_buffering                 off;
    proxy_http_version                      1.1;

    proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
    proxy_cookie_path                       off;

    # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
    proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
    proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;
    proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;
    proxy_pass http://dummy;
  }
  server_name  dummy.prod.com;
}
```